# Why am I getting login screen when running minimal Spring Boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm following this tutorial [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-tutorial-with-hello-world-example/).

It's a very basic tutorial where you create a Spring Boot app, which I did using the spring initialzr in Intellij. I added the following dependencies:

- Web
- Jersey
- HATEOAS
- JPA
- Security
- HSQLDB

And then a simple controller for the "/" route. However, when I run and view the application in localhost:8080, I see a login screen:

[image]

I assume it has to do with one of the dependencies? I can't find anywhere in the code where a login screen should appear.

Comment: Its because you have added spring security dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security includes that login page as a default. You can customize it, and configure many other aspects of Security, by adding a `SecurityConfig.java` file with the appropriate incantations (there are many [examples](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/sample/config/SecurityConfiguration.java) and [tutorials](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) online).

As @Tanmoy writes, the (generated each startup) username/password to enter is being output in the console.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.0-M1/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form for details. Essentially, Spring Security configures a set of filters for your views. One of those ensures that non-logged-in users are redirected to a login page.

Answer (score 2):

You added spring security so you are getting the login screen. you can see the generated password from the log

Comment: I see the generated password. What do I use for the username?

Comment: @doctopus Hello, normally is "user".

Answer (score 1):

Hey you have added security dependency that's why it is happening.

Solution

> 1. Use this Login Information
>
>    - Username : User
>    - Password:  From Console
> 2. Suggested Solution

Go to **application.properties** file in location */ProjectName/src/main/resources/application.properties*

```
spring.security.user.name=anyname
spring.security.user.password=pass123
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned that it is because of Spring Security Dependency. So if you do not want it, you can disable it as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
    {
     security.httpBasic().disable();
    }
}
```

You wont see login page again on including the above class in your code.